# Algorithm to rank some items

Tags: algorithms, ranking

Say I have some items with values

```
3.3
3.4
6.2
8.8
4.1
```

and I want to rank them as follow

```
   item   rank
    3.3    5 
    3.4    4
    6.2    2
    8.8    1
    4.1    3
```

I tried something like ths

```
rank = item number(say 3.3)/higest item number(8.8)
```

This gives me ranking in floating point number but I want it in integer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the ratio to calculate the rank? you could sort the data by descending and assign a sequence to it.